# Swiftui - function to return different value based on another variable

Tags: swiftui

I have a view (view1) to display different data, and I would like that view to change based on another variable:

```
struct View1: View {

let array = myFunc()

var body: some View {
    
VStack {

   Text("\(settings.score)")
        List {
        ForEach(0..<array.count) { section in
    
        NavigationLink(destination: RowDetailView(array: array[section])) {

        RowView(array: array[section])
        }
        }
}
    }
```

In another view I establish an Observable object:

```
class GameSettings: ObservableObject {
@Published var score = 1
}
```

That all works well elsewhere in other views. I can update it as needed.

I have a function to obtain the array variable, and I would like it to return a different array depending upon the current value of "score".

```
func myFunc() -> [arrayModel] {
@StateObject var settings = GameSettings()
if settings.score == 1 {
var array = [ arrayModel(example: example) ]
return array
}



else if settings.score == 2 {

var array = [ arrayModel(example: example) ]

return array

}
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. I have tried various tweaked versions of this, but can't find how to properly implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can u share the code of your `arrayModel`

Comment: Having `@StateObject var settings = GameSettings()` *inside* your function doesn't make sense -- `score` will *always* be `1`, since it's a new instance. Do you mean to be passing in `GameSettings` from somewhere else, maybe?

Comment: Yep, I probably do need to pass it. How would I implement that here?